# Backbone JS event on document click

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to working with Backbone JS and I'm creating a Backbone View. I made this View so when you click the template it calls function `highlight` to add the `highlight` class to my element:

```
var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // ...

    events: {
        "click .player": "highlight"
    },

    // ...

    highlight: function () {
        this.$el.find('.player').addClass('highlight');
    }

});
```

I want to make it so when I click anywhere else in the application, I remove the `highlight` class from this element.

I could declare a click handler on the `document` and remove the `highlight` class from there:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.player.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

And then use `event.stopPropagation()` in the highlight function to prevent bubbling:

```
var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // ...

    highlight: function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        this.$el.find('.player').addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

This works and exhibits the functionality I'm looking for. However this doesn't exactly leverage the backbone framework. Is there a proper way of doing this in Backbone JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Backbone View's `events` hash only looks at things within that view's `$el`.

If you want to remove the highlight of a player when another player is clicked, you can have your player views rendered within a player collection view, which can watch for click events.  You could then:

```
handleClick: function(e) { 
    this.$(".player").removeClass('highlight');
    this.$(e.currentTarget).addClass('highlight');
}
```

If you want to handle all clicks regardless of whether they occur within a Backbone.View's $el, then you probably do want to use a global handler.

Note, untested.

If you post details of the structure of your application perhaps a better solution could be suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up building a global event handler afterall. Tough to put everything in the Backbone context!

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).on('click', function(e){
        Backbone.trigger('document-click-event', e);
    });


var Popup = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
   ........
    initialize: function(options) {
      _.extend(this, options);
      this.listenTo(Backbone, 'document-click-event', function(e) {
         if (!$(e.target).closest(this.el).length && !$(e.target).closest(this.field).length && !$(e.target).closest('.ui-datepicker').length) {
            this.hide();
         }
      }, this)
.....
```